# Help needed to pass client side values in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can i pass value from grid view to a pop up in client side. I have a edit button in the grid view and when user clicks that the value(EditExpiresBy) from selected row should be in a text box in the pop up.

```
<asp:Panel ID="EditPanel" runat="server">
            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_EditExpiresBy" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:Button ID="btn_EditSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btn_EditSave_Click" />

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
```

and a PopupControlExtender.

How can I pass the value in client side. help needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to have a `DetailsView` that is linked to the `SelectedValue` property of your `GridView`.  You can put the `DetailsView` in the popup, and it will display whatever was selected in the `GridView`

**Sample `DetailsView`** *Note: you would be putting this in place of the* txt_EditExpiresBy *TextBox control*

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="detailsView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    DataKeyNames="yourIDField" DataSourceID="detailsSqlDataSource" 
    Height="50px" Width="287px" >
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpiresBy" HeaderText="Expires By" 
            SortExpression="ExpiresBy" />
        <%--Whatever other fields you want to include--%>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

**Sample Data source (for the `DetailsView`)**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="detailsSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Your Connection String" SelectCommand="SELECT [ExpiresBy] FROM [tableName] WHERE yourTableID = @yourTableID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="yourGridView" Name="yourTableID" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

See the `ControlParameter` in this DataSource looks at the ID of the row that was selected in the `GridView` and uses that to populate the `DetailsView`.

Let me know if any of this is not clear and I'll try to explain myself better, this is just the way I usually do it.